# COMO LEER EL SIGUIENTE ARCHIVO CON OPERADOR >>

Tags: c++, entrada, operador

Me dan el siguiente archivo txt:

```
#Rutas
R1 5 (34.520418555522845,69.20082090000005) (52.50786264022465,13.426141949999987) (7.406652727545182,12.344585699999925) (-0.18659558628491132,-78.4305382) (40.40051528912146 ,-3.5916460749999635)
R2 8 (58.695433501291085,-96) (35.08690549340541,-103.72339606166992) (-12.055345316962327,-77.04518530000001)  (40.40051528912146,-3.5916460749999635) (37.943768420529985,104.13611175000005) (-27.787075486256633,133.28132295)  (35.673473752079516,139.71038800000008) (62.88647107195116,61.551173617626986)
R3  5    (17.246400332673307,   -19.670602940234403) (4.283635422564345,-74.22403995000002) (51.528868434293244,    -0.10159864999991441) (62.88647107195116,61.551173617626986) (37.943768420529985,104.13611175000005)
R4  11 (14.422538164676899,-87.63432239999997) (48.85887766623369,2.3470598999999766)
 (24.725939314861463 ,46.822528799999986) (58.695433501291085,-96) (35.08690549340541,-103.72339606166992) (-12.055345316962327,-77.04518530000001) (40.40051528912146,-3.5916460749999635) (37.943768420529985,104.13611175000005) (-27.787075486256633,133.28132295)  (35.673473752079516,139.71038800000008) (62.88647107195116,61.551173617626986)
 
R5  5   (52.76081718996433,8.747611999999986) (-19.051901092806112,29.15280180000002)
(-34.61590069251671,-58.433298449999995) (58.695433501291085,-96) (52.76081718996433,8.747611999999986)
```

Ahora bien, tengo que leerlo sin los espacios y sin las tabulaciones que incluye pero no consigo filtarlo.

He programado el siguiente operador de entrada:

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream &is, Ruta &ruta){
            string codigo;
            Punto p;
            string numpuntos;

            getline(is,codigo,' ');
            ruta.code = codigo;
            ruta.puntos.clear();
            
            getline(is,numpuntos,' ');
                
            while((is.peek()!= '\n') && !is.eof()){
                
                if(is.peek() == ' '){

                    is.ignore();
                    
                }else{
                    is>>p;
                    ruta.puntos.push_back(p);
                }
            } 
            if (!is.eof()){
                string linea;
                getline(is,linea);
            } 
            return is;          
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Al usar el operador de extracción `>>` de `cout` hay que tener en cuenta que a la hora de leer un número o una cadena, los separadores (espacios, tabuladores, saltos de línea) que se encuentren antes del valor a leer se descartan automáticamente. Esta característica simplifica enormemente el proceso de lectura, si lo sabes emplear correctamente.

Esto es facil de comprobar;

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::cout << a << ',' << b;
```

Estas líneas leeran correctamente los valores `a` y `b` en entradas tan dispares como:

```
1[espacio]2
1[tabulador]2
1[salto][tabulador][espacio][salto][espacio][espacio][tabulador]2
```

Aprovechando esta característica, la lectura del archivo es prácticamente trivial.

Para empezar, leemos una línea del archivo:

```
std::string linea;
std::getline(is, linea);
```

Ahora vamos a procesar esta línea, para lo cual la vamos a introducir en un stream:

```
std::sstream ss(linea);
```

Leemos el código

```
ss >> ruta.code;
```

Leemos el número de puntos

```
size_t numPuntos;
ss >> numPuntos;
```

Y, a continuación, leemos el número de puntos pedidos:

```
ruta.puntos.reserve(numPuntos);

for( size_t i=0; i<numPuntos; i++ )
{
    Punto p;
    ss >> p;
    ruta.puntos.push_back(p);
}
```

Claro que también podríamos escribir directamente en el array de puntos:

```
ruta.puntos.resize(numPuntos);
for( size_t i=0; i<numPuntos; i++ )
{
  ss >> ruta.puntos[i];
}
```

¿Y la lectura de los valores de los puntos?

Pues algo así:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & in, Punto & punto)
{
    char c;
    while( true )
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        if( c == '(' ) break;
    }

    in >> punto.x;

    while( true )
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        if( c == ',' ) break;
    }

    in >> punto.y;

    while( true )
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        if( c == ')' ) break;
    }

    return in;
}
```

Con lambdas quedaría algo más compacto y ordenado:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & in, Punto & punto)
{
    auto discardLambda = [&in](char toFind)
    {
        while( true )
        {
            char c;
            in >> c;
            if( c == toFind ) break;
        }
    };

    discardLambda('(');

    in >> punto.x;

    discardLambda(',');

    in >> punto.y;

    discardLambda(')');    

    return in;
}
```

O, si lo prefieres con funciones independientes:

```
void discardLambda(std::istream & in, char toFind)
{
    while( true )
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        if( c == toFind ) break;
    }
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & in, Punto & punto)
{
    discardLambda(in, '(');

    in >> punto.x;

    discardLambda(in, ',');

    in >> punto.y;

    discardLambda(in, ')');    

    return in;
}
```